# Remove custom header subpage with remove_submenu_page

Tags: wordpress

How can I remove `Header` and `Background` subpages from `Appearance` submenu?

`remove_submenu_page` works great with `Themes` and `Menus`, but I can't seem to find a way to remove `Header` and `Background`!

Here's an example:

```
   // working just fine:
   remove_submenu_page( 'themes.php', 'themes.php' );
   remove_submenu_page( 'themes.php', 'nav-menus.php' ); 
   // not working:
   remove_submenu_page( 'themes.php', 'themes.php?page=custom-header' ); 
   remove_submenu_page( 'themes.php', 'themes.php?page=custom-background' );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Following code in your theme's function.php

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme','remove_twentyeleven_options', 100 );
function remove_twentyeleven_options() {

remove_custom_background();
remove_custom_image_header();

}
```

Answer (score 3):

`remove_custom_background();` is deprecated as of WordPress 3.4

Use `remove_theme_support( 'custom-background' );` instead.